# Unwind query matching by label instead of id

Tags: neo4j, profiling

I have the following query:

```
profile
unwind [{match_id: 5298}, {match_id: 5294}] as record
match (m:match)
where id(m) = record.match_id
return m
```

And this is the given plan:

[image: query plan showing label scan]

If I remove the query from the unwind it seeks by id as expected. Is there a hint I can give it to seek by id?

Comment: Which version do you test this with? I think that might be an issue which was resolved in 2.2.2?

Comment: I just tried 2.2.2 and the same issue exists. Well at this point it seems like a bug though so i'll file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't a simple:

```
match (n)
where id(n) in [5298, 5294]
return n
```

be sufficient? Instead of the static array you might pass in a parameter being an array.

I've found no way to do `NodeByIdSeek` when a more complex statement is used like `record.match_id` in your example.

Comment: This is a simplified example for stack overflow. I need the unwind to unroll a large data structure and perform more processing.